# Grails sub query

Tags: mysql, grails, subquery, grails-orm

I have a mysql query

```
SELECT a.* FROM table a,
        (SELECT NAME, MAX(VERSION) AS VERSION FROM table b
        WHERE b.version <= 2.3
        GROUP BY NAME ) c
        WHERE a.name=c.name
        AND a.version=c.version;
```

which I want to convert to grails query. I have tried and made it as

```
Table.executeQuery("from Table a, (SELECT NAME, MAX(VERSION) FROM Table b WHERE b.VERSION <= :fieldVersion GROUP BY b.NAME) c where a.NAME=c.NAME AND a.VERSION=c.VERSION",[fieldVersion:version]);
```

But the code shows the error near **,(SELECT** and it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

Table.findAll("from Table as a,(SELECT NAME, MAX(VERSION) AS VERSION FROM table b WHERE b.version <= ?
GROUP BY NAME ) c WHERE a.name=c.name AND a.version=c.version",[2.3])

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def executeQuery(String query) {
    def db = new Sql(dataSource)
    db.rows(query)
}
```

What you return is depending on the query itself

Comment: It will not return the domain object rather it returns the rows. I want the objects. Thanks.